# Parse API CSV via URL

Tags: javascript, php, database, api, csv

I need advice on dealing with API data. I want to know what's the best approach to parse a csv file with the format of the URL below.

URL: URL…com../..api/..csv/..1234apikey=..123456ABC

I would like to process the results and insert the values into a database.

The data will change overtime, so the implementation needs to be dynamic.

The format of the data is below:

```
"position","player.href","name.text","total","letter","days","hits","index","url"
"1","javascript:void(0);","Jamie","1","url"
"T2","javascript:void(0);","Tom","3","A","1","68","url"
"T2","javascript:void(0);","Sam","3","A","2","8","27","3","url"
"T2","javascript:void(0);","Joe","3","A","3","7","27","4","url"
"5","javascript:void(0);","Pat","2","A","4","7","28","5","url"
"T6","javascript:void(0);","Sean","1","A","5","6","29","6","url"
```

Comment: [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str_getcsv). Start experimenting.

Comment: Thanks Sverri, I believe   
file_get_contents() doesn't work with a URL that does not contain a .csv filename

Comment: Most PHP file functions can be used to load content from websites. The type of file does not matter; if the URL returns data then the function will read that data. For example, `file_get_contents('http://google.com/');`,  works fine. If it does not work for you then the server is probably configured to not allow it, but that is an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edit - I didn't know you didn't know how to pull data from the API.  I would use file_get_contents() or CURL to query the URL.  Typically

```html
file_get_contents("URL: URL…com../..api/..csv/..1234apikey=..123456ABC");
```

I would loop the data by splitting by "\n" and then split it by ",".  In the foreach you could then drop it into a MySQL table or whatever you want to do.

```html
<?php

$data = "your api data";
$splitlines = explode("\n",$data);

foreach($splitlines as $line)
{
 $linedata = explode(',',$line);
 $position = $linedata[0];
 $player = $linedata[1];
 ... etc.
}
```

Comment: Use PHP's build in CSV parsing routines: if you simply explode on a comma, you'll break strings wrapped in quotes that happen to contain commas.