# How to parse CSV file in PHP and store fields in a database?

Tags: php, database, api, csv

I need help parsing the following a CSV file in PHP, so I can insert the contents into a database.

I know I use `file_get_contents()` but after that I feel a bit lost.

What I'd like to store.

- Collection1 - **events.text** & **date**
- Collection2 - **position** & **name.text** & **total**

I'm not sure how best structure the data to insert into a database table.

```
"**collection1**"
"events.href","**events.text**","**date**","index","url"
"tur.com/events/classic.html","John Deere Classic","Thursday Jul 9
- Sunday Jul 12, 2015","1","tur.com/r.html"
"collection2"
"**position**","name.href","**name.text**","**total**","index","url"
"--","javascript:void(0);","Scott","--","2","tur.com/r.html"
"--","javascript:void(0);","Billy","--","3","tur.com/r.html"
"--","javascript:void(0);","Jon","--","4","tur.com/r.html"
"--","javascript:void(0);","Bill","--","5","tur.com/r.html"
"--","javascript:void(0);","Tim","--","6","tur.com/r.html"
"--","javascript:void(0);","Carlos","--","7","tur.com/r.html"
"--","javascript:void(0);","Robert","--","8","tur.com/r.html"
"--","javascript:void(0);","Rod","--","9","tur.com/r.html"
```

Comment: You'll have to invent the datastructure of your database yourself. Parsing of CSV is done using standard PHP functions: fgetcsv.

Comment: Hi thanks I'm aware of that, it's just confusing. I can read in lines of csv but how do you separate those into variables to insert. Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: How are you getting on with this?

Answer (score 0):

As per [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256833/parse-api-csv-via-url), I think this needs to be broken down into sections. As it stands it is rather too broad to answer.

- Read the information using `file_get_contents()`. Make sure this works first, by echoing it to the console. (It sounded from your other question that you felt this would not work if the URL does not have a `.csv` suffix. It should work regardless of the file extension - try it. If it fails it may be dependent on cookies or JavaScript or some other problem).
- Design and create your table structure in MySQL. It seems like you have two tables. They should both have a primary key. Are they related in some fashion? If so, perhaps one has a foreign key to the other one?
- Explode your text file on the new line character and loop across the resulting array of lines.
- If your CSV data has a title row in the first row position, delete that from your array.
- For each line, read the elements of interest using PHP's build-in CSV parsing functions, and store them in variables.
- Pass these variables to a custom function that saves the data.
- For each save, you'll need to do an `INSERT`. I recommend using PDO here. Make sure you bind your parameters.

Where you get stuck on a *specific* problem, you can ask a new and focussed question. At present, the task is to break things down into discrete and researchable pieces.

One trick worth remembering is this shortcut to the PHP manual. If you do not know how `fgetcsv` works, for example, type `php.net/fgetcsv` into your browser address bar, and the PHP site will find the function for you. The documentation is excellent.